# Realm transaction causes GC sweep ui freeze

Tags: android, realm, freeze

My ui is freezing when during a transaction in Realm. Getting lot's of GC sweeps during transaction:

```
Starting a blocking GC Explicit
Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 21(1312B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 13% free, 106MB/122MB, paused 480us total 24.157ms
```

This is the first time I'm experiencing this issue. Have been using Realm in lot's of project without coming across something like this. Even if delete all code and just keep the realm.begintransaction and realm.committransaction calls it freezes so I nailed the problem down to the transaction itself. But given the fact that this also happens if there is nothing between the begin & commit it has nothing to do with the size or query itself.

```
public static void insertValueForKeyInSession(final String sessionUuid, final String key, final String value){
    Realm realm = App.getCoreRealmInstance(App.getContext());

    RealmQuery<DataResponse> query = realm.where(DataResponse.class);
    query.equalTo("sessionUuid", sessionUuid);
    query.equalTo("key", key);
    final RealmResults<DataResponse> result = query.findAll();

    if (result.size() > 0) {
        DataResponse response = result.get(0);

        realm.beginTransaction();
        response.setValue(value);
        realm.commitTransaction();

    } else {
        DataResponse dataResponse = new DataResponse();
        String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        dataResponse.setSessionUuid(sessionUuid);
        dataResponse.setUuid(uuid);
        dataResponse.setKey(key);
        dataResponse.setValue(value);
        realm.beginTransaction();
        realm.copyToRealm(dataResponse);
        realm.commitTransaction();
    }
    realm.close();
    Log.d(TAG,"insertValue Stopped");

}
```

Comment: 106MB memory usage doesn't sounds normal. Can you check if you app has any leaks? If memory is fine in your side, would you please share you apk with us? to help@realm.io , and tell us how to reproduce it. I can help to debug.

Comment: @beeender I was able to fix this problem, posting what it was as an anwser. If you need more information from mee I am happily to do so;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me some time but I was able to fix this. Stil don't know the exact cause do so if anybody can get any info on that, great:) After lot's and lot's of tries I finally was thinking about all the things I recently changed in this project.

I had to use a Migration & configuration so whereas before I would get a realm instance through the normal Realm.getInstance(Context context). I had changed my code to App.getCoreRealmInstance(App.getContext()).. This method:

```
RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                .schemaVersion(dbVersion)
                .migration(new Migration())
                .build();
return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

Changes I made:

1. Following method only gets called once at startup and sets the default configuration..

   RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
               .schemaVersion(dbVersion)
               .migration(new Migration())
               .build();
   Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration)
2. The App.getCoreRealmInstance method now only returns Realm.getDefaultInstance();

Comment: Did that mean you used a Activity as context instead of a Application context when called `App.getCoreRealmInstance` ? Do you save a ref to the context from `App.getCoreRealmInstance` some where? Realm doesn't save a ref to the `context` passed to `getInstance`. So if that is the problem, you might have some leaked activity before.

Comment: No, not realy. I also First tried removing all Migration & configuration code and just returning Realm.getInstance(context) from the App.getCoreRealmInstance. That also solved the issue without changing any other code that would leak an activity or anything.. But since I need the migration I used this solution to get everything working again..

Comment: So before you solve the issue, there is a chance that `setDefaultConfiguration` gets called many time in different threads?

Comment: No, I didn't use setDefaultConfiguration before. I used the getInstance method accepting a configuration as a parameter ( Realm.getinstance(configuration) ) everytime..

Comment: OK, then. I still cannot imagine what happened to your app before. Please let me know if the same problem happens to you again in the future. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From https://realm.io/docs/java/0.76.0/#writes it looks like "writes block each other, and will block the thread they are made on if other writes are in progress." Is it possible there is another write in progress?

Comment: No, I double checked this and I'm only doing this one thing. I also checked to see if realm.isInTransaction() returns true but that's also not the case. I also tried switching this code (although it's absolutely a small transaction) to a completely new Thread & using the async transaction realm provides but even then the ui freezes.

Comment: Are you able to use Realm.executeTransaction() instead, from 0.77? It automatically commits or cancels as appropriate, maybe that will clear the block?

Comment: Yes, this also had the same problem. But I was able to nail it down by now. Posting it as an answer now..